# Does anyone know of a good unaffiliated review of Rockworks?

Tags: 3d, cross-section, subsurface

I've been struggling to find a good software package for drillhole data management, subsurface geology modelling, and visualization (both 2D and 3D): something that can also be used to produce sophisticated vertical and inclined cross sections.  I took the Gemcom GEMS course and found the software too complex (database setup, plotting) and rigid. It's also astronomically expensive. I evaluated Target for ArcGIS by Geosoft using their tutorial and data and found it lacking features, buggy and slow. (Dumbed down version that works with ArcGIS.) As I was to evaluate the full standalone version of Target I stumbled over a recommendation for Rockworks by RockWare. The videos on their site look amazing. Too good to be true to be honest. **I would like to read some unaffiliated reviews of the software but am having a difficult time finding anything valuable.** Can someone please provide a link a share a few thoughts about the software package?

Comment: What did you find wrong with Target for ArcGIS? The "dumbed down" concerns me - maybe you need to upgrade versions? The learning curve or risk wouldn't be as great as switching to a new software program entirely.

Comment: I used the dataset downloaded from Geosoft website. Many outputs are static and no shapefile equivalent is generated. Assay profile has a bug; generated shapefile is very different from the static output, numerous critical error messages troughout the evaluation (followed the provided tutorial), reference grids only avaialbe as "static" output, 3D viewer is external, drill holes "run off" the grid, etc., etc. Just not sufficient for me as I am planning to use 1000's of drillholes, almost all deviated/inclined. Geosoft provided some workarounds but I need something robust and simple.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've had a bit of experience with Rockworks (ver. 14.0) and am not incredibly impressed with it. While it's fairly easy to get data into the system, generating any kind of presentation quality (let alone publication quality) diagrams was extremely unintuitive. I gave up and drew the few cross-sections I needed by hand. I also came to realize that the cross-sections that Rockworks did produce were not 3D correct - when I compared locations where two sections intersect, the structural surface elevations did not match.

Recently, a colleague of mine who is re-developing a regional framework for the Floridan aquifer introduced me to [Leapfrog Hydro](http://www.leapfroghydro.com/hydro/) (formerly Aranz Hydro). He is a big proponent of this software, though he hasn't been using it very long himself. According to him, it is more intuitive to use, very robust, and is 3D correct when outputting cross-sections. I believe you can make 3D animations with the software as well.

I haven't had a tremendous amount of experience with either of these pieces of software so please take my words with a grain of salt. However, from what I've seen and experienced I would recommend looking into Leapfrog before Rockworks.

Comment: Excellent. Thanks. I've come across Leapfrog but did not pay much attention to it. I will take a closer look. Thanks for the insight too. I've become wary of packages that sound too good to be true.

Comment: Also, there looks to be a relatively cheap [training course](http://igwmc.mines.edu/short-course/speed_up.html) ($200) on using Leapfrog Hydro and applying the results to drive groundwater models. You may not be interested in the latter part of that, but if you can get a plane ticket and paid registration it might be a good way to see if the software is something that you could use.

Comment: I think the Leapfrog Mining package looks more like something we need. Already looked into training for that but can't find anything.

Comment: Our contact is Thom Krom at [Touch Water](http://www.touchwater.net/) in Denmark. He's a super nice guy and may be able to point you in the appropriate direction for your needs. If you can't find his contact info on his website let me know and I'll send it to you.

Answer (score 1):

@Jakub We haven't been collecting reviews, but here are some from Google.

http://igwmc.mines.edu/software/igwmcsoft/RockWorks_Review.html

or

http://www.swhydro.arizona.edu/archive/V6_N2/dept-softwarereview.pdf (same review in publication *Southwest Hydrology*, March/April 2007.

@whuber Thanks for fixing my sig block faux pas.

Answer (score 0):

RockWare has released RockWorks15 with an overhaul of the user interface that makes the program easier to use.  You can [download](http://www.rockware.com/product/productDemo.php?id=165) a full working model demo from the RockWare web site.

Comment: Please read our FAQ concerning conventions and policies about posting personal information and references to commercial code.  You have done well by clearly identifying yourself as a representative of RockWare and providing a link.

Comment: -1 I don't think this is an answer to the question

Comment: Thanks Tom. Can you provide a link to some user reviews?

Comment: @Celenius You're right, it's better off as a comment.  However, new users can't post comments.  A mod can convert responses to comments, but this one has a unique status because it's a response from the vendor of the software in question.  I thought the community might consider it to be a kind of indirect reply so I did not change it to a comment.  I think we should welcome vendor participation for the unique insight it can offer, but if anyone has feelings to the contrary, I invite you to start a meta thread about this: it's a good way to have your voice heard (and acted on).

Comment: I see. I think that is reasonable - perhaps the answer should mention this? (Though now it is explained here).

Answer (score 0):

As a follow-up to Tom Breshahan's comment; 
(1) I am a RockWare employee (geologist/programmer) so I'm obviously biased.
(2) We released RockWorks16 on 7/1/13.
(3) We have made over 1,446 changes since the release of RockWorks14 (detailed list: http://www.rockware.com/rockworks/revisions/index.html)
(4) You can download the full program and use it for two weeks without paying anything thereby allowing a side-by-side comparison with other products.
(5) I apologize for not directly answering the question - our user testimonials are also biased and that's why I recommend a try-with-your-own-data-before-you-buy evaluation.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using Rockworks since the early DOS days. Granted, it may not produce the prettiest graphics output or be the most robust system for resource modeling, but for casual, or entry-level earth science application, it has a lot of bells & whistles. Where these are located is not always intuitive, but their help files are extensive--not to mention their online support, which I would rate among the top.

Often you will be wanting to use Rockworks in conjunction with some other software--depends what your needs are. Someone mentioned Leapfrog as an option. From what I heard and seen, it is very good at 3-D renderings, however--a bit pricey. If not purchasing a full-blown license, I believe you can "rent" it on an hourly, daily, etc. basis.

As an alternative to Leapfrog, I use Voxler, developed by Golden Software I believe. Very intuitive, good extensive help manual as well as online support. And a price that won't break the bank.